# Yellow screen on page load

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am developing a Wordpress website. Everything is going according to the plan except that I started to get a yellow screen while the page is loading after I made some changes on the single.php and inserted some HTML and JS on the first line.

This does not affect the site in any other way then it's not that pretty to see. Presumably that yellow loading screen is a result of my changes on the single.php. Why is this happening and how could I restore a normal white screen? I attach a screenshot of the "bug" while the page is loading so you can see the issue.

Let me know if you want to see the code (I don't know if it is relevant). This issue happens only when I want to visit a page that uses single.php.

**UPDATE:**

This is the code I added:

```
<div class="row-fluid IFKbanner_events"> <!-- IFKbanner_events is a styling class that can vary from page to page. Do not mind it if ot does not exist or has other names on other pages -->
    <!-- Top bar -->
<div id="superettan-topbar"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
       var teamId, offset, topbarDiv = "superettan-topbar";
       teamId = 9604;
       (function () {
           var sup1 = document.createElement('script'); sup1.type = 'text/javascript'; sup1.async = true;
           sup1.src = 'http://topbar.superettan.se/?teamId=' + teamId + '&offset=' + offset;
           (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(sup1);
       })();
   </script>
    <img src="http://website.se/nywebbsida_test/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/header1920x283.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Really, with the yellow-pages tag?

Comment: Seeing the code might be useful.

Comment: Yello-pages is gone. I didn't thought it had to do with the company but with some other users that had related problems

Comment: @CiprianD done. Hope it helps!

Comment: You should start by moving that div inside the body tag. Right now it's even before the doctype declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you what those divs and js code on single pages at the top, you should edit header.php like so. Place this where you need to be. This should resolve your issue.

```
<?php if(is_single()){
       //add the code here
      }
?>
```

Comment: This solved the problem! I was thinking wrong. Thanks for the heads up! :)